# Splitting a string using re module of python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string

```py
s = 'count_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]'
#I have to capture only the field 'count_EVENT_GENRE'
field = re.split(r'[(==)(>=)(<=)(in)(like)]', s)[0].strip()
#o/p is  'cou'
# for s = 'sum_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]'  o/p = 'sum_EVENT_GENRE'
```

which is fine

My doubt is for any character in `(in)(like)` it is splitting the string `s` at that character and giving me first slice.(as after "cou" it finds one matching char i:e `n`). It's happening for any string that contains any character from `(in)(like)`.

Ex : `'percentage_AMOUNT' o/p = 'p'`

as it finds a matching char as 'e' after `p`.

So i want some advice how to treat (in)(like)  as words not as characters , when splitting occurs/matters.

please suggest a syntax.

Comment: Perhaps, you need `r'[=><]=|in|like'`

Comment: What is the desired output for this input? Why?

Comment: The `[ ]` matches only one character in that wordlist, so it means "either ( or = or ) or > or i or n or l or k or e".  You probably mean `(==|>=|<=|in|like)`

Comment: perhaps use `re.findall(r'^\w+', s)[0]` instead?

Comment: Use https://www.debuggex.com/ for regex edits. It giving visual representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question, the `[(==)(>=)(<=)(in)(like)]` is a character class matching single characters you defined inside the class. To match sequences of characters, you need to remove `[` and `]` and use alternation:

```
r'==?|>=?|<=?|\b(?:in|like)\b'
```

or better:

```
r'[=><]=?|\b(?:in|like)\b'
```

You [code](https://ideone.com/gAAfsZ) would look like:

```
import re
ss = ['count_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]','coint_EVENT_GENRE = "ROMANCE"']
for s in ss:
    field = re.split(r'[=><]=?|\b(?:in|like)\b', s)[0].strip()
    print(field)
```

However, there might be other (easier, or safer - depending on the actual specifications) ways to get what you want (splitting with space and getting the first item, use `re.match` with `r'\w+'` or `r'[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+'`, etc.)

**If your value is at the start of the string and starts with lowercase ASCII letters, and then can have any amount of sequences of `_` followed with uppercase ASCII letters**, use:

```
re.match(r'[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*', s)
```

[Full demo code](https://ideone.com/vJThVZ):

```
import re
ss = ['count_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]','coint_EVENT_GENRE = "ROMANCE"']
for s in ss:
    fieldObj = re.match(r'[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*', s)
    if fieldObj:
        print(fieldObj.group())
```

Comment: in case s =  ' coint_EVENT_GENRE = "ROMANCE"' . look at coint it has 'in'. so when i apply r'[=><]=|in|like' it gives me 'co' by splitting at 'in' by co+in+t. So r'\w+' will be better.. But how to avoid that from r'[=><]=|in|like' by adding any \w+ \w in that syntax.

Comment: Use word boundaries: `r'[=><]=?|\b(?:in|like)\b'` and I see that you have a single `=` - then you need to make the `=` optional by appending `?` after it. Why not use `re.match(r'[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*', s)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first word of your string, then this should do the job:

```
import re
s = 'count_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]'
field = re.split(r'\W', s)[0]
# count_EVENT_GENRE
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with using `split`?

```
>>> s = 'count_EVENT_GENRE in [1,2,3,4,5]'
>>> s.split(' ')[0]
'count_EVENT_GENRE'
>>> s = 'coint_EVENT_GENRE = "ROMANCE"'
>>> s.split(' ')[0]
'coint_EVENT_GENRE'
>>>
```

Comment: I actually mentioned this in my answer (see *splitting with space and getting the first item*). However, `split` does not make sure the substring meets a specific pattern and if you supply arbitrary string, its first non-whitespace chunk will always be returned.

Comment: Nicely done and most simple. Thanks. But  I have to apply some more parsing on the o/p and have more categories for which @Wiktor  answer gave me a future insight. So I have to accept Wiktor's answer. I upvoted your solution. Thanks Again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry Wiktor, I didn't see your reference to split

Comment: It is perfectly ok, and no need to feel sorry, just when the idea is so basic, I tend to just post a comment. In your shoes (I mean if I had the same rep amount), I'd probably also post this answer :)